# How to convert a dataframe in long format into a list of an appropriate format?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apriori

I have a dataframe in the following long format:

[image: 1]

I need to convert it into a list which should look something like this:
[image: 2]

Wherein, each of the main element of the list would be the "Instance No." and its sub-elements should contain all its corresponding Parameter & Value pairs - in the format of "Parameter X" = "abc" as you can see in the second picture, listed one after the other.

Is there any existing function which can do this? I wasn't really able to find any. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dplyr solution

```
require(dplyr)
df_original <- data.frame("Instance No." = c(3,3,3,3,5,5,5,2,2,2,2),
                      "Parameter" = c("age", "workclass", "education", "occupation", 
                                      "age", "workclass", "education", 
                                      "age", "workclass", "education", "income"),
                      "Value" = c("Senior", "Private", "HS-grad", "Sales",
                                  "Middle-aged", "Gov", "Hs-grad",
                                  "Middle-aged", "Private", "Masters", "Large"),
                      check.names = FALSE)
    
# the split function requires a factor to use as the grouping variable.
# Param_Value will be the properly formated vector
df_modified <- mutate(df_original,
                      Param_Value = paste0(Parameter, "=", Value))
# drop the parameter and value columns now that the data is contained in Param_Value
df_modified <- select(df_modified,
                      `Instance No.`,
                      Param_Value)

# there is now a list containing dataframes with rows grouped by Instance No.
list_format <- split(df_modified, 
                     df_modified$`Instance No.`)

# The Instance No. is still in each dataframe. Loop through each and strip the column.
list_simplified <- lapply(list_format, 
                          select, -`Instance No.`)

# unlist the remaining Param_Value column and drop the names.                      
list_out <- lapply(list_simplified , 
                   unlist, use.names = F)
```

There should now be a list of vectors formatted as requested.

```
$`2`
[1] "age=Middle-aged"   "workclass=Private" "education=Masters" "income=Large"     

$`3`
[1] "age=Senior"        "workclass=Private" "education=HS-grad" "occupation=Sales" 

$`5`
[1] "age=Middle-aged"   "workclass=Gov"     "education=Hs-grad"
```

The posted data.table solution is faster, but I think this is a bit more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting an error in the second line of code. It says the following `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `3436108600`, `8135121`, `8134395`, `66398212`, `49332`, etc. don't exist.`

Comment: That's not very helpful. What's the name of the function throwing the error? It sounds like you need to tidy your data. Do the dataframe column names actual match those in the code here? How are you handling NA values?

Comment: This works perfectly fine, just like I wanted it! Thank you so much! I did not change anything else in my data.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(data.table)
your_dt <- data.table(your_df)

dt_long <- melt.data.table(your_dt, id.vars='Instance No.')
class(dt_long) # for debugging
dt_long[, strVal:=paste(variable,value, sep = '=')]

result_list <- list()

for (i in unique(dt_long[['Instance No.']])){
  result_list[[as.character(i)]] <- dt_long[`Instance No.`==i, strVal]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The following is the error I get in the fourth line. Can you please help with what exactly does that line of code do?



Error in `:=`(strVal, paste(Parameter, Value,  : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: did you execute the second line? `your_dt <- data.table(your_df)` - it is necessary to make it work

Comment: Yes, I did. It runs perfectly fine till the third line with the "dt_long" dataframe getting created as well. But the fourth line gives the error as I mentioned.

Comment: that's strange. Ok, try to run with `melt.data.table()` instead of `melt()`; also run `class(dt_long)` after that (see updated answer) and tell us what it gives

Comment: if that doesn't work, we won't be able to help you without having a real piece of your data.  If you can share a fragment of your table (as _data_, not picture) - that would be more efficient. To get a reproducible fragment (first 10 rows), run `dput(your_df[1:10,])` and share the output in your question.

Comment: After running with `melt.data.table()` and running `class(dt_long)` I get `"data.table" "data.frame"`. But again I get an error in the same line as previously mentioned. But I guess my problem is resolved. @icj has provided a solution below which is giving the desired output I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: don't forget to click "Accept" on icj's answer if it solved your question

Comment: Done! Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference. Here is the R base oneliner to do this. `df` is your dataframe.

```
l <- lapply(split(df, list(df["Instance No."])), 
            function(x) paste0(x$Parameter, "=", x$Value))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code is getting executed, but I'm getting a list comprising of all Instance Nos. and an "=" at the last. Doesn't actually look like what I wanted. But rather it looks something like this:
("Instance No.1", "Instance No.2", "Instance No.3",...."=")